# Hi guys I got a task to do but I'm a little stuck, my images are not showing up or am I doing something wrong and need more code

Tags: javascript

### Here is the task

---

Create a file cars.js. Within cars.js:
o Create 5 car objects using a constructor function.
o Each car object should have the following properties: make, model,
colour, image, registration number, price.
o Each car object should also include a showMore() method. This
method should display a dialogue that displays all the details about
the specific car object. Hint: See more about  here.
o Create a function that will be used to display the make, model, and
image of each car object in ‘cars.html’ when ‘cars.html’ is loaded.
● Whenever a user clicks on an image of a car, the showMore() method
should be called and all the information about the car, including the
registration number, price, etc. should be displayed.
Completed the task(s)?

```js
const body = document.body;
const dialog = document.createElement("dialog");

class Cars {
    constructor(make, model, color, image, registration, price) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.color = color;
        this.image = image;
        this.registration = registration;
        this.price = price;
    }

    click() {
        body.appendChild(dialog);
        dialog.innerHTML =
            "Colour: " + this.color + ", Registration: " + this.registration;
        dialog.setAttribute("open", "open");
    }
}

const car1 = new Cars("BMW", "M3","images/image1.jpg", "Black", "NP 123 000", "R1,400 000");
const car2 = new Cars("Volkswagon", "MK1","images/image2.jpg", "Red", "NP 321 000", "R100,000");
const car3 = new Cars("Ford", "Escort","images/image3.jpg", "Blue", "NP 465 487", "R1.400 000");
const car4 = new Cars("Volkswagon", "MK8","images/image4.jpg", "Silver", "NP 023 145", "R800,000");
const car5 = new Cars("Volkswagon", "MK2","images/image5.jpg", "Silver", "NP 007 007", "R450,000");

let btn1 = document.getElementById("first-car");
let btn2 = document.getElementById("second-car");
let btn3 = document.getElementById("third-car");
let btn4 = document.getElementById("fourth-car");
let btn5 = document.getElementById("fifth-car");

btn1.onclick = () => car1.click();
btn2.onclick = () => car2.click();
btn3.onclick = () => car3.click();
btn4.onclick = () => car4.click();
btn5.onclick = () => car5.click();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Car sales</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cars.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>VEES CAR SALES</h1>

    <div id="car-details">
      <button id="first-car">first-car</button>
      <br />
      <button id="second-car">second-car</button>
      <br />
      <button id="third-car">third-car</button>
      <br />
      <button id="fourth-car">fourth-car</button>
      <br />
      <button id="fifth-car">fifth-car</button>
    </div>

    <script src="cars.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - where are you stuck? Are there errors in your dev console?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] (in the latter, the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem" is pertinent).

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes the specific problem**"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `click` function needs to create an element, `document.createElement('img')` for `this.image` to be set into the `image` element's attribute, `src` using `Element.setAttribute` see this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const body = document.body;
        const dialog = document.createElement("dialog");

        class Cars {
            // you miss the src in constructor
            constructor(make, model, src, color, image, registration, price) {
                this.make = make;
                this.model = model;
                this.color = color;
                this.image = image;
                this.registration = registration;
                this.price = price;
                // set src of image
                this.src = src;
            }

            click() {
                body.appendChild(dialog);
                // add image tag inside dialog 
                dialog.innerHTML = "<img src='" + this.src + "'>" +
                    "Colour: " + this.color + ", Registration: " + this.registration;
                dialog.setAttribute("open", "open");
            }
        }

        const car1 = new Cars("BMW", "M3", "images/image1.jpg", "Black", "NP 123 000", "R1,400 000");
        const car2 = new Cars("Volkswagon", "MK1", "images/image2.jpg", "Red", "NP 321 000", "R100,000");
        const car3 = new Cars("Ford", "Escort", "images/image3.jpg", "Blue", "NP 465 487", "R1.400 000");
        const car4 = new Cars("Volkswagon", "MK8", "images/image4.jpg", "Silver", "NP 023 145", "R800,000");
        const car5 = new Cars("Volkswagon", "MK2", "images/image5.jpg", "Silver", "NP 007 007", "R450,000");

        let btn1 = document.getElementById("first-car");
        let btn2 = document.getElementById("second-car");
        let btn3 = document.getElementById("third-car");
        let btn4 = document.getElementById("fourth-car");
        let btn5 = document.getElementById("fifth-car");

        btn1.onclick = () => car1.click();
        btn2.onclick = () => car2.click();
        btn3.onclick = () => car3.click();
        btn4.onclick = () => car4.click();
        btn5.onclick = () => car5.click();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Car sales</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cars.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>VEES CAR SALES</h1>

    <div id="car-details">
      <button id="first-car">first-car</button>
      <br />
      <button id="second-car">second-car</button>
      <br />
      <button id="third-car">third-car</button>
      <br />
      <button id="fourth-car">fourth-car</button>
      <br />
      <button id="fifth-car">fifth-car</button>
    </div>

    <script src="cars.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```